# How to change first pagination link URL in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to make pagination in CodeIgniter 4 like below:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients
http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/2
http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/3
```

So here is my method:

```
public function index($page = 1){

    
    /**
     * page redirect to http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients
     * if the user visits to http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/1
     */
    $segment = null != $this->request->getUri()->getSegment(3);
    if($segment == 'page'){
        if ( $this->request->getUri()->getSegment(4) == 1) {
            return redirect()->to( base_url('admin/all-clients') );
        }
    }
    

    $perPage = 10;
    $offset = ($page - 1);
    $total = $this->clientsModel->countAll();


    /**
     * get all clients
     */
    $clients = $this->clientsModel
            ->select('clients.*, subject.subject_text')
            ->join('subject', 'clients.client_subject = subject.id')
            ->paginate($perPage, '', $offset + 1);
    
    /**
     * get pager links
     */
    $pager = $this->clientsModel->pager;

    $pager->setPath('admin/all-clients/page', 'client-group');
    $links = $pager->makeLinks($page, $perPage, $total, 'bs_custom', 4, 'client-group');
    

    echo view('admin/allClients', [
        'page_title' => 'All Clients',
        'clients' => $clients,
        'pager_links' => $links,
    ]);
}
```

here is my route:

```
$routes->get('all-clients', 'ClientsController::index');
$routes->get('all-clients/page/(:num)', 'ClientsController::index/$1');
```

In pagination links, the first page URL is **http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/1**. But I want **http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/** and the rest of the pagination links should be
**http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/2**, **http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/3** ....

So, my question is how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to handle the redirect by yourself since your configured ROUTES already do it.

You can keep everything as is, **except the redirect block that you have to remove** and you will see it's working already :

```
public function index($page = 1){
    echo $page;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After going to the third page, if I mouse hover on first-page button or no 1 page, It is showing http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/1. So technically this page data i.e. http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/1 and http://localhost:8080/admin/all-clients this page data is the same. That's why I set redirect.

Comment: You want it to be the same, no?

Comment: I want to change first link i.e. localhost:8080/admin/all-clients/page/1 to localhost:8080/admin/all-clients

Answer (score 0):

First your param define $page=1 but your url is empty.

and don't use getSegment in controller. this is a main reason.

Try this

```
public function index($page = ""){
      $page=$page==""?1:$page;
    }
```